# filter jython-generated property fields for getters/setters from dir() result

Tags: jython

I ran into a problem using java objects in jython today because jython is trying to be intelligent and automatically creates properties for (simple) getter/setter methods - For each method a field with the leading `get`/`set` removed and the next letter converted to lowercase is created:

```
//java code
class MyClass {
    public List<Thing> getAllThings() { ... }
    public List<Thing> getSpecificThings(String filter) { ... }
    public void setSomeThing(SomeThing x) { ... }
    [...]
}

#jython code
obj = MyClass()
hasattr(obj, "allThings") #-> True
hasattr(obj, "specificThings") #-> False because getSpecificThings has a param
hasattr(obj, "someThing") #-> False BUT
"someThing" in dir(obj)   #-> True
```

The last line summarizes my problem here - the result of `dir` contains these fields (even when executed on `obj.class` instead of `obj`). I need a list of all methods callable on the object, which for my objects basically is the result of `dir` without these properties and filtered to exclude everything inherited from `java.lang.Object` and things starting with an underscore (the purpose of this is to automagically convert some python classes to java equivalents, e.g. dicts to Maps). In theory I could use `__dict__` which doesn't contain them, but this would mean I'd have to recursively evaluate the base classes' `__dict__`s too, which I would like to avoid. What I am currently doing is seeing if the attribute actually exists and then check if it has an `argslist` attribute (meaning it is a method), which is true for every `dir` entry except for the generated properties:

```
for entry in dir(obj):
    #skip things starting with an underscore or inherited from Object
    if entry.startswith("_") or entry in dir(java.lang.Object): continue
    #check if the dir entry is a fake setter property
    if not hasattr(obj, entry): continue
    #check if the dir entry has an argslist attribute (false for getter props)
    e = getattr(obj, entry)
    if not hasattr(e, "argslist"): continue
    #start actual processing of the entry...
```

The problem with this approach is that the objects in question are interfaces to beans and a getSomething method typically fetches data from a database, so the `getattr` call for a property makes a roundtrip to the DB which can take multiple seconds and waste tons of memory.

Can I stop jython from generating these properties? If not, does anybody have an idea how I can filter out the properties **without accessing them first**? The only thing I could think of was checking if `dir` contains a method named `get`/`set<property>`, but this seems hackish and could generate false positives, which must be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was easier than anticipated. While a `hasattr` of the property is `True` for an object instance, it is `False` for the objects class if the get-method in question is not static - the class doesn't have the property as you can't execute the method on it. The updated loop now looks like this:

```
for entry in dir(obj):
    #skip things starting with an underscore or inherited from Object
    if entry.startswith("_") or entry in dir(java.lang.Object): continue
    #check if the dir entry is a fake property
    if not hasattr(obj.class, entry): continue
    #check if the dir entry has an argslist attribute (false if not a method)
    e = getattr(obj, entry)
    if not hasattr(e, "argslist"): continue
    #start actual processing of the entry...
```